# Amazon Redshift Spectrum: Out Of Memory Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I'm trying to use Amazon Redshift Spectrum to query some data that are on S3.
I've created an external table on data stored in Parquet (about 5 GB of data).

Every time I try to run a simple query like the one below I get the error: `Out Of Memory`

```
  SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4 FROM spectrum.mytable WHERE col1<>'' AND col2<>'' LIMIT 100;
```

Am I doing something wrong?
I'm running a Redshift cluster with 2 nodes of type dc1.large ( 15 GiB of Memory each!)

Comment: What went out of memory? Your cluster or the machine (laptop, desktop etc) on which you're attempting to fetch data?

Comment: the cluster. It's an error returned by Amazon Redshift

Comment: The best way to look at this is to check the explain plan and run a bunch of queries assessing if generally it works well. Like `select count(*) from spectrum.mytable` or `explain select ...` Check if you see the correct file format etc.